# When the ties are the majority in Wilcoxon

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

I´m doing a comparation in a sample with an n=300. I did the wilcoxon rank test to compare if there were difference in the individuals in two situations.

The problem is that the ties are allways huge, for example 230 ties in 300, but the test gives me a p-value < 0,005 and i dont know how to interpret the result since the nule hypothesis is "there arent significattive differences", wich means that in my case there are significative differences but the ties are alway huge!

Comment: How many distinct values do you have? You could test the approximation by simulation, calculating p-value via permutations.

Answer (score 0):

When a two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test, as implemented in R, compares two samples of size as large as $n = 300$ the computation of the P-value uses an approximation
that is often not adversely affected by ties.

Consider the following fictitious
gamma-distributed data,
rounded to integers.

```
set.seed(805)
x1 = round(rgamma(300, 3, .1))
x2 = round(rgamma(300, 3, .11))
```

Because of the rounding, there are many ties; there are only 70 uniquely different values among 300 in the first sample and only 63 in the second.

```
length(unique(x1))
[1] 70
length(unique(x2))
[1] 62
```

Boxplots show that the two samples are of similar shape, so it is OK to use the Wilcoxon RS test
to assess any difference in location.

```
boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

```
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2.00   18.00   27.00   30.43   40.00  124.00 

summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    2.0    15.0    23.0    27.1    37.0    93.0
```

The test gives P-value $0.013 < 0.02 = 2\%,$ so the
difference in locations is significantly different at
the 2% level. [There is no warning message about the many ties.]

```
wilcox.test(x1,x2)

      Wilcoxon rank sum test 
      with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
W = 50256, p-value = 0.01328
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
```